# Change the coordinate system in After Effects

Tags: after-effects

I'm recreating a Sketch composition in AE. To ease the process I would like to change the position of 0,0 from the center of the comp to bottom left. That would make it possible for me to translate the position values from Sketch to AE w/o doing any calculations.

Is it possible to change the position of 0,0 from the center of a composition to e.g. bottom left? Preferably w/o using expressions.

Comment: The coordinates of the composition are [measured](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/selecting-arranging-layers.html#coordinate_systems_composition_space_and_layer_space) from the top left and there doesn't appear to be a way to change it.

Comment: What stops you from entering all your position values, then selecting everything and dragging it into place? Would that work?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the Sketch2Ae plugin by the Google Motion Design team? It works amazingly well. Here's a link to it:

https://google.github.io/sketch2ae/

I usually couple this plugin with the RepositionAnchorPoint plugin from aescripts, as Sketch2Ae seems to mess up anchor points. I personally prefer my anchor points to be aligned center to an element within AE. Here's a link to it:

https://aescripts.com/repositionanchorpoint/

Once Sketch2Ae builds all your layers, select them all and reposition all anchor points with one click using this plugin.

Both plugins are free, with RepositionAnchorPoint being optionally free.